# Open page from bookmarklet, but, make it like a modal window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a bookmarklet which can (obviously) be called by the user anywhere:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://*****.com/***.html?url=
'+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href),'my_page_name',
'left=200,top=200,width=480,height=500,personalbar=0,
toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=1')})()
```

How can I make this like a modal window, meaning no ugly browser window borders - should I use jquery or something like in the bookmarklet URL and if so, how?

Comment: jQuery in a bookmarklet?  I dare say that is going too far.

Comment: It's jQueryUI (dialog in particular) that would give you the ability to have a dialog without a new browser window.  But I think that is a lot to do in a bookmarklet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the approach [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Stable) uses.
Basically you insert an external JS file into your page when you click on the bookmark.

```
<a href="javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','PATH_TO_JS ','PATH_TO_ICON','BASE_URL','#startOpened');">My bookmark</a>
```

Just change **BASE_URL**, **PATH_TO_JS** and **PATH_TO_ICON** to what you need it to be.
Also, don't forget the *"http://"* in the BASE_URL, unless you want to use a relative path.

Your external JS file could contain a script which adds an element to the page which hovers over others. I recommend using the CSS in [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#popovers) to figure out how to make a reliable modal window.

**Edit --**

To help you out I wrote [a small demo](http://bijtel.com/stackoverflow/bookmark/). It consists of 2 files:

- bookmark.html - adapted firebug code to create bookmark which adds script dynamically
- bookmark.js - creates a modal with an iframe

bookmark.html

```
<a href="javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','bookmark.js','','http://www.bijtel.com/stackoverflow/bookmark/','#startOpened');">Bookmark</a>
```

bookmark.js

```
(function() {
  var script;

  if(!window.jQuery) {

    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);

  }

  (function check_if_loaded() {

    if(!window.jQuery) {

      setTimeout(check_if_loaded, 50);

    } else {

      (function($) {

        var
          $dark_bg = $('<div></div>').css({'z-index': '1000', 'background-color': '#000000', 'opacity': '0', 'position': 'absolute', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'}),
          $iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>').css({'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', 'border': 1, 'overflow': 'hidden'}).prop({'src': 'http://bijtel.com/cv/', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%', 'scrolling': 'no'}),
          $close = $('<div></div>').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': 0, 'right': 0, 'padding': '5px 10px', 'cursor': 'pointer', 'color': '#ffffff', 'font-size': '10pt', 'font-family': 'verdana'}).html('close &times;');
          $modal = $('<div></div>').css({'z-index': '1010', 'background-color': '#ffffff', 'opacity': '0', 'position': 'absolute', 'top': '10%', 'left': '10%', 'width': '80%', 'height': '80%', 'box-shadow': '7px 7px 5px #333'}).append($close, $iframe);

        $('body').css({'padding': 0, 'margin': 0}).prepend($dark_bg, $modal);

        $dark_bg.animate({'opacity':0.5}, 400);

        $modal.animate({'opacity':1}, 400);

        $close.on('click', function() {
          $dark_bg.animate({'opacity': 0}, 400, function(){ $dark_bg.remove(); });
          $modal.animate({'opacity': 0}, 400, function(){ $modal.remove(); });
        });

      }(window.jQuery));

    }

  }());

}());
```

Demo at: http://bijtel.com/stackoverflow/bookmark/

Comment: Demo link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the subject, but looking at the delicious.com bookmarklet I noticed some parameters to limit which parts of the browser window will be shown:

```
(function() {
    f = 'http://www.delicious.com/save?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title)  + '&v=5&';
    a = function() {
        if (!window.open(f + 'noui=1&jump=doclose', 'deliciousuiv5', 'location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,width=550,height=550')) location.href = f + 'jump=yes'
    };
    if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        setTimeout(a, 0)
    } else {
        a()
    }
})()
```

The parameters I'm talking about are the `location`, `links`, `scrollbars` and `toolbar`. That does not make it modal, though, and I doubt there is a feature for that (I'm assuming browser windows are independent of each other). But they provide a "cleaner" window nonetheless...

**Update**: check out [this link](http://t.rc.vc/delicious/generator.html). Basically, what the bookmarklet does is to create a new script tag and append it to the body. I'm assuming you could do anything you want in that script, including create a jQuery dialog the way you wanted (in fact, this bookmarklet **does** use jQuery, but it's embedded in the script itself; see the [source](http://t.rc.vc/delicious/js/delicious.js)).

Here's the code. I wouldn't use this bookmarklet myself (since I'd have to provide my username/password in the clear), but it's a starting point for you to do yours:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.setAttribute('language', 'javascript');
e.setAttribute('src', 'http://t.rc.vc/delicious/js/delicious.js?username=***&password=***');
e.setAttribute('id', 'delicious_submitter');
document.body.appendChild(e);
void(0);
```

Obs.: in both examples, I stripped the `javascript:` part and formatted the code for readability.